# Rails partial show latest 5 kases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have my application setup with a few different partials working well. I have asked here how to get a partial working to show the latest entry in the kase model, but now I need to show the latest 5 entries in the kase model in a partial.

I have duplicated the show most recent one partial and it's working where I need it to but only shows the last entry, what do I need to change to show the last 5?

_recent_kases.html.erb

```
<% if Kase.most_recentfive %>
<h4>The most recent case reference is <strong><%= Kase.most_recentfive.jobno %></strong></h4>
<% end %>
```

kase.rb

```
  def self.most_recentfive
    first(:order => 'id DESC')
  end
```

Thanks,

Danny

**EDIT**

```
  def self.most_recentfive
      all(:order => 'id DESC', :limit=>5)
    end
```

If I add the above code I get the following Error Message:

```
NoMethodError in Dashboard#index

Showing app/views/kases/_recent_kases.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `jobno' for #<Array:0x105984c60>
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <% if Kase.most_recentfive %>
2: <h4>The most recent case reference is <strong><%= Kase.most_recentfive.jobno %></strong></h4>
3: <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def self.most_recentfive
    all(:order => 'id DESC', :limit=>5)
  end
```

EDITED TO ADD:

Then, in your partial, to display the results, you do

```
<% if Kase.most_recentfive %>
<h4>The most recent five case references are
   <% Kase.most_recentfive.each do |k|%>
       <strong><%= link_to k.jobno, k %></strong><br />
   <% end %>
</h4>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried that a second ago but got the error message I added to my question above.

Comment: You're getting an error because your "most_recentfive" method is returning an array (of kase) and array doesn't have a jobno.  You need to loop through the five kases in the array and output each of them.

Comment: Could you elaborate - I'm pretty stupid when it comes to rails.

I need to add five calls for kases in the partial?

Comment: Edited to add how to display the results -- at the right point in your ERB, you iterate over the kases and display each one.

Comment: Great, that worked a treat thanks!

If I wanted to make them link to the relevant kase show view would I just add link_to?

Comment: Yep!  And remember, if this answer worked for you, please select it as your accepted answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Done that, marked the answer as brilliant!

I added link_to but it just outputs a link to /.

<% Kase.most_recentfive.each do |k|%>
    <ul class="dashboard_recentkases">
 <li><%=link_to k.jobno%></li>
 </ul>
   <% end %>

Comment: You need to specify both the text to put in the link (k.jobno) and the item to link to (k).  I've altered my partial example above to include a link_to.